# How to make selected text in JTextArea into a String?

Tags: java, swing, listener, highlight, jtextarea

I'm working on a simple word processor with java swing and layouts, and I'm trying to figure out how to make individual blocks of text bold, italics, or different font sizes instead of the whole block of text changing at once in my JTextArea.

Is there some way to initialize a String as the user highlights the text in the JTextArea with their mouse? I would love it if there was some sort of ActionListener or something for JTextArea which could detect all this and easily save anything as a string, but I'm not sure if this is possible. Something like this would be great:

```
String selectedtext;
JTextArea type;

class TextPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public TextPanel()
    {
        type = new JTextArea();
        type.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(type);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        selectedtext = e.getSelected();
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize my answer is geared more towards your end goal and not the question you asked, sorry about that.

Comment: Don't be sorry, I actually switched all my `JTextArea`s to `JTextPane`s even before I saw your comment and I'm learning to use Attributes and Styles now. Thanks for giving me the basic information for `JTextPane`s in your answer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTextArea doesn't have any built-in functionality that will do this, but:

In order for someone to select text, they have to click on the text area, drag and release the click. So, attach a MouseListener and implement the mouseReleased method to check if any text was selected, and if so to save it as a string:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (textArea.getSelectedText() != null) { // See if they selected something 
        String s = textArea.getSelectedText();
        // Do work with String s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to accomplish this with a `JTextArea`, you will need something that supports rich display of text like a `JTextPanel` and you'll need to define styles for it, applying these styles to specific regions.

[Here](https://github.com/bbuck/DragonConsole/blob/master/com/eleet/dragonconsole/util/DocumentStyler.java) is an example of a utility class for created styles (linked to give example of defining styles). The `addNewStyle` and `changeFont` are the two most important methods to reference. The `addNewStyle` method shows how to add a predefined style to the document that you can reference when inserted (mostly for pasting should you want to past with a format). The `changeFont` method shows how to create a style and apply it to a region (in the method the region is from `0` to the end of the document - so the entire document).

You'll probably need these styles to be crafted dynamically and so you'll need to fetch them from the region if one exists (that I've not done). All of this is done with a `StyledDocument`

And example of appending text with a style to a `StyledDocument` (purely for example) is:

```
styledDocument.insertString(
                styledDocument.getLength(), textToInsert,
                styledDocument.getStyle(styleName));
```

It's been some time since I worked with `JTextPane` s and `StyledDocuments` so most of this is pulled from the project where I did the work. I wish I could give you more info rather than just a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JTextComponent#setCaretPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29) followed by [JTextComponent#moveCaretPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#moveCaretPosition%28int%29) to highlight/select

Answer (score 1):

For detecting selection changes in JTextArea, it would be better if you make use of the CaretListener.

```
jTextArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener(){
   public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent ce)
   {
        int dot=ce.getDot();
        int mark=ce.getMark();

              if(dot!=mark)
              selectedText=jTextArea.getSelectedText();
              else selectedText=null;
   }
});
```

Now, if you want to do some operations with the selected text when mouse is dragged, you could do it, because the selectedText is updated.

Answer (score -1):

JTextArea doesn't have that capability. You should look at
[JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

It can display html , so you can use bold tags and whatever you need..

Comment: This isn't much of an answer, but that doesn't make it invalid. I doubt that a `JEditorPane` is what the OP was looking for though.

Comment: @izuriel this answer can going correct way, JTextPane/JEditorPane has built-in support for HighLighter for OPs ask `how to make individual blocks of text bold, italics, or different font sizes instead of the whole block of text`, please more see in Oracle tutorial

Comment: @izuriel - The author of the question was mentioning the fact that he's building a small scale word processor. I doubt that the OP desires a word processor that functions like gedit or notepad.

Comment: @Protostome `JTextPane` is a better option for a text editor than a `JEditorPane` which is a simple HTML processor. @mKorbel, I'm quite aware you must not have paid any attention to my answer.