# delete selected text from JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am developing a GUI in Java using the Netbeans IDE and swing forms. Here I want to delete the selected text from the `Jscrollpane` using a DELETE button which I have added by using an ADD button. I am able to delete the entire text but not the selected one. I have searched on Internet but could not get any help. Below is the code which I have tried. Any suggestions will be helpful for me.

```
private void buttondelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter ft = new FileNameExtensionFilter( "arxml Files", "arxml" );
    chooser.setFileFilter(ft);
    jScrollPane1.getContainerListeners(); 
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "You Selected : " + list.getSelectedValue());
    if (evt.getSource() == buttondel )
    {
         File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        log.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492817/how-to-get-selection-from-jtextpane#12496636 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859289/how-to-make-selected-text-in-jtextarea-into-a-string is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `JScrollPane` must have a `JTextArea` where you will be putting the content. Add a listener to the `JTextArea` and get the selected text on an action performed. Then delete the selected text

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion, but can you Show me the source code how it should be implemented